# Android HTTP post not sending post valules

Tags: android, http-post

Really having problem with this issue.
The below code suppose to sent to POST values (username,password) to the server and the server should just response with the var_dump of GET and POST.

PHP CODE:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

ANDROID CODE:

```
InputStream is = null;

//http post
try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url + "?test=test");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        // place them in an array list
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "1123"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123123"));

        // add array list to http post
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        Log.i("Network", "POST URL: " + url);
        Log.i("Network", "POST ARGS: " + jsonObj.toString());

    } catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("Network", "POST Error in http connection " + e.toString());

    }
```

But all i get is:

```
array(0) {
}
array(1) {
   ["test"]=> string(4) "test"
}
```

I have tested the server with curl: curl -F 'username=test' http://xx.xx.xx.xx/test.php
And it gives me correct return:

```
array(1) {
   ["username"]=> string(9) "test"
}
array(0) {
}
```

So what am i doing wrong in the android post ?

Comment: your data obviously isn't json. what's the point of `httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set your `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. You can either do not set the `Content-Type` header or set it manually to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: ahh, ok, that worked. is there anyway that i can substitude the ArrayList with:
StringEntity post_entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(post_entity);

Comment: that won't be any more a `POST` of `NameValuePairs`. so please accept it if it was the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, it was the correct answer for NameValuePairs, just wanted to know if you got a solution for the `StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);` by any change ?

Comment: than you will have to set your `Content-Type` to `application/json` and process the body differently on the server side.